# Rundeck - Reference Job: ${node.name} as Node filter

Tags: rundeck

on Rundeck (3.2.6-20200427) I created two Jobs called testjob and subjob.

testjob should call reference job subjob.

In workflow of subjob, I added a task "Job Reference" and selected another job. There I set "Run as a" to "Node Step". See screenshot testjob-task1.

[image]

Then I entered '${node.name}' as Node filter.

[image]

Unfortunatelly, if I run testjob, then I got error:

```
1. generic/subjob: No nodes matched for the filters: NodeSet{includes={name=${node.name}, dominant=false, }}
```

What did I wrong? I didn't add option into workflow because I read, it is not needed if the job is run as a Node Step. Am I wrong? Also I'm wondering, why the error log doesn't tell like '...NodeSet{includes=node01, dominant=false, }}', it seems that the variable is not set properly there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing directly with one job `${node.name}` doesn't work as a filter, you can use some option (or string) that matches any node in your model source, as the following example (parent-child workflow using some option example).

Parent Job:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='optparent' value='node00' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>3f94993d-665c-45da-8233-f95c0f69f665</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>Parent</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <jobref name='Child' nodeStep='true'>
          <arg line='-mynodes ${option.optparent}' />
          <uuid>badd942a-f4e7-41de-9588-1b5d255e34d8</uuid>
        </jobref>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>3f94993d-665c-45da-8233-f95c0f69f665</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

Child Job:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='mynodes' value='node00' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <dispatch>
      <excludePrecedence>true</excludePrecedence>
      <keepgoing>false</keepgoing>
      <rankOrder>ascending</rankOrder>
      <successOnEmptyNodeFilter>false</successOnEmptyNodeFilter>
      <threadcount>1</threadcount>
    </dispatch>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>badd942a-f4e7-41de-9588-1b5d255e34d8</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>Child</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <nodefilters>
      <filter>${option.mynodes}</filter>
    </nodefilters>
    <nodesSelectedByDefault>true</nodesSelectedByDefault>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "hi"</exec>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>badd942a-f4e7-41de-9588-1b5d255e34d8</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```